# PPM to TFS Connector

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, automation, agile-project-management

I want to connect from Project and Portfolio Management Center to my TFS. 
In the sense if I log any CSR/Ticket in PPM, connector should be in place where it automatically will enter Bug/Story in TFS.

Its like PPM entry -- Connector -- TFS

I know there is one for QC Connector which enters Bugs in Rally, But not sure about MS TFS.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Did you mean you need a extension to auto create bug/story based on CSR/Ticket in PPM you have created there?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for PatrickLu-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box feature for this in TFS side. You may have to do this yourself such as create a customize process.

Not familiar with how to fetch CSR/Ticket in PPM. However in TFS side, you could auto create work items such as Bug/Story using Rest API. You can call into [the REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) or the Client Object model and use that to query wok items and to create new work items. The API broadly used and there is a lot of information out there in terms of blog posts and the like. Or you can create a small [console application that also uses the same Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130322.aspx).

Comment: I have tried but its failing but still I got direction so good for me. Thanks a lot Patrick..